# How to get corresponding cell value of max from different column

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I am just trying to get those record who have highest discounted percentage. For that i used max function. But i am not able to fetch it's corresponding column(nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice) value. I am getting wrong value in nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice column.(MYSQL).

```
select bs.nBusinessDetailsId,bs.strBusinessName,bs.strBusinessDescription,
pkg.nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice,pkg.nDiscountPercentage
from tblbusinessdetails bs
INNER JOIN tblvendorbusinesscategory vbs ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId=vbs.nBusinessDetailsId
INNER JOIN tblpackageassociatedoutlets pkga ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId=pkga.nOutletId
INNER JOIN tblpackagedetails pkg ON pkga.nPackageId=pkg.nPackageId
where vbs.nMainCategoryId=9;
```

By using above query i was getting repeated data like this:
[image]

For that i added group by clause for bs.nBusinessDetailsId. Then i was getting 2nd highest nDiscountPercentage which is wrong. I want 1st highest nDiscountPercentage and it's corresponding nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice

Here is my query.

```
select bs.nBusinessDetailsId,bs.strBusinessName,bs.strBusinessDescription,
pkg.nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice,max(pkg.nDiscountPercentage)
from tblbusinessdetails bs
INNER JOIN tblvendorbusinesscategory vbs ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId=vbs.nBusinessDetailsId
INNER JOIN tblpackageassociatedoutlets pkga ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId=pkga.nOutletId
INNER JOIN tblpackagedetails pkg ON pkga.nPackageId=pkg.nPackageId
where vbs.nMainCategoryId=9 group by bs.nBusinessDetailsId;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by *its corresponding column value*.

Comment: @O.Jones Done.. can you please check

Comment: What's your question???  .. you have an error?  show th error message .. unexpected  result ?? add  a proper data sample, your actula result and the expected result

Comment: @scaisEdge ok...

Comment: @scaisEdge can you please check. I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the subquery for maxPerc  group by nBusinessDetailsId (without the price)

```
select  t.nBusinessDetailsId
        ,t.strBusinessName
        ,t.strBusinessDescription
        ,pkg.nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice
        ,t.maxPerc
from (
    select bs.nBusinessDetailsId
        , bs.strBusinessName
        , bs.strBusinessDescription
        , max(pkg.nDiscountPercentage) maxPerc
    from tblbusinessdetails bs
    INNER JOIN tblvendorbusinesscategory vbs ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId=vbs.nBusinessDetailsId
    INNER JOIN tblpackageassociatedoutlets pkga ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId=pkga.nOutletId
    INNER JOIN tblpackagedetails pkg ON pkga.nPackageId=pkg.nPackageId
    where vbs.nMainCategoryId=9 
    group by bs.nBusinessDetailsId
) t  
INNER JOIN tblpackageassociatedoutlets pkga ON t.nBusinessDetailsId=pkga.nOutletId
INNER JOIN tblpackagedetails pkg ON pkga.nPackageId=pkg.nPackageId
    AND t.maxPerc =pkg.nDiscountPercentage
```

Comment: showing syntax error where from bracket ends: ")" is not valid at this position expecting: EOF, BEGIN, CACH, CHECKSUM, COMMIT

Comment: answer updated ..  removed  ;  .. hope this work ..and added comma

Comment: "Unknown column 't.maxPrice' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the `nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice` value for the row with the largest `nDiscountPercentage` .

That's best retrieved with a fairly tricky subquery

```
              SELECT a.* 
                FROM tblpackagedetails a
                JOIN (SELECT MAX(nDiscountPercentage) nDiscountPercentage,
                             nPackageId
                        FROM tblpackagedetails
                       GROUP BY nPackageId
                     ) b ON a.nDiscountPercentage = b.nDiscountPercentage
                        AND a.nPackageId = b.nPackageId
```

You can test this. Its inner query finds the largest discount for each package. Then it uses that value in a JOIN to give you a subset of the rows from `tblpackagedetails` having the largest percentage discount for each `nPackageId`. If more than one row has the same exact largest discount, you'll get them all and have duplicates in your final result set.

Then you join it in to your main query.

```
select bs.nBusinessDetailsId,bs.strBusinessName,bs.strBusinessDescription,
       pkg.nPackageDiscountedAdultPrice,pkg.nDiscountPercentage
  from tblbusinessdetails bs
 INNER JOIN tblvendorbusinesscategory vbs 
            ON  bs.nBusinessDetailsId=vbs.nBusinessDetailsId
 INNER JOIN tblpackageassociatedoutlets pkga 
            ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId=pkga.nOutletId
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT a.* 
                FROM tblpackagedetails a
                JOIN (SELECT MAX(nDiscountPercentage) nDiscountPercentage,
                             nPackageId
                        FROM tblpackagedetails
                       GROUP BY nPackageId
                     ) b ON a.nDiscountPercentage = b.nDiscountPercentage
                        AND a.nPackageId = b.nPackageId
            ) pkg ON pkga.nPackageId=pkg.nPackageId
 where vbs.nMainCategoryId=9;
```

Notice that the `MAX() ... GROUP BY ...` aggregate is moved to the subquery.

Comment: It's giving me same result.